# Why are the loops in my program not terminating?

Tags: c, performance, while-loop, greedy, cs50

My code is meant to display the least number of coins that a person would need for a certain amount of money. I converted the value into cents and then used loops to test for every different coin. You may see printf for variables that I used for testing purposes to see where it was going wrong. The loops just continue forever and do not subtract the value of C as many times as the loop repeats. ex. `c-25` stays at 475 cents instead of going down by 25 each time the loop repeats (for value of $5.00).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
float c=0;
int i=0;
int y=0;

    printf("How much change do you owe?\n");
    c=GetFloat();
    c=c*100;
    printf("%f\n", c);
    do
    {
        c-25;
        printf("%d\n", c-25);
        if (c>25)
        {
            i++;
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
        while (c>=25);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    do
    {
        y=c-10;
        if (y>0)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
        while (y>10);
    if (y<=10)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    do
    {
        y=c-5;
        if (y>0)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
        while (y>5);
    if (y<=5)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    do
    {
        y=c-1;
        if (y>0)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
        while (y>1);
    if (y==0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

*Note: This is for the "Time For Change" program in CS50*

Comment: **Do not use `float` if you need exact values!**

Answer (score 4):

`c` is never changed.

There is no effect to the statement:

```
c-25;
```

which should probably be:

```
c = c - 25;
```

or

```
c -= 25;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some remarks on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
// use self-explanatory and meaningful names of your variables 
float c = 0;
int i = 0;
int y = 0;

// input
printf("How much change do you owe?\n");
c = GetFloat();
c = c * 100;
// print input
printf("%f\n", c);

// add comment explaining the purpose of this loop 
do{
    c = c - 25; // corrected to decrement by 25

    printf("%d\n", c);
    if (c > 25){
        i++; 
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}while(c >= 25);

printf("%d\n", i);

// add comment explaining the purpose of this loop 
do{
    y = c - 10;
    if (y > 0){
        i++;
    }
}while(y > 10);

// add comment explaining the purpose of this condition statement
if (y <= 10){
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

// add comment explaining the purpose of this loop
do{
    y = c-5;
    if (y > 0){
        i++;
    }
}while(y > 5);

// add comment explaining the purpose of this condition statement
if (y <= 5){
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

// add comment explaining the purpose of this condition statement
do{
    y = c-1;
    if (y > 0){
        i++;
    }
}while(y > 1);
// add comment explaining the purpose of this condition statement
if(y == 0){
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
}
```

The main problems come from the *termination conditions* and the *counter variables* incrementation/ decrementation, which are wrong or missing and that is leading to infinite loops.